# Append dir to PATH

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, bashrc

I'm trying to localy add a dir to the global `$PATH` variable. I added the following to my `.bashrc`.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$VRS/bin
```

But `PATH` seems to get concatenated to itself over & over every time I open a shell (i.e. `PATH` keeps growing). Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your script/`.bashrc`, just use:

```
PATH=$PATH:$VRS/bin
```

so that the change is temporarily only for the script/shell session you're running. The `export` command will make the change permanent.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, each time you open a shell, your `.bashrc` is executed. And thus, with your current code, your `PATH` will grow indefinitely.

If you only need this change to path for your shell, you can just remove the `export`, and let in your `.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:$VRS/bin
```

If your need to have this change more global, move your line (and the code defining your `$VRS`) to file `~/.profile`, but by keeping the `export`. This file is only executed at login, not each time your open a shell.

Or even to `/etc/profile` if you want this change to be for all users.

Comment: Nice, more options than mine. I didn't think of the user profile and global profile files :)